# Creating table for properties

Tags: java

I am not a guru in Java, but I've got a task in which I have to create some tree list with properties, e.g. like this:

```
depth1
    property1 | checkbox
    property2 | combobox
depth2
    property3 | string
    property3 | button
```

where for every property it is possible to have different controls. I was struggling with JXTreeTable, but due to lack of documentation I am completely confused whether it is even appropriate for this. Maybe I can achieve this with simple JTreeTable instead of JXTreeTable? That would be even better. Could you suggest me any solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

Try this:

Create a `class` `Property` to store property like `property1 | checkbox`

And then create as many `Property` objects and add them to a `properties list`.

Then `put` the `key` like `depth1` and the corresponding  `properties list` in a `map`.

Thats it!

Property class:

```
public class Property {

private String propertyName;
private String controlType;
private String controlValue;

//getter setters
```

}

Code to put a sample value like

> depth1
>
> ```
>     property1 | checkbox
>     property2 | combobox
> ```

goes here:

```
Map<String, List<Property>> myCustomTree = new HashMap<String, List<Property>>();

    Property p1 = new Property();
    p1.setPropertyName("property1");
    p1.setControlType("checkbox");
    p1.setControlValue("TRUE");//may be true/false or checked/unchecked

    Property p2 = new Property();
    p2.setPropertyName("property2");
    p2.setControlType("combobox");
    p1.setControlValue("A String that is contained in my combobox");

    List<Property> properties1 = new ArrayList<Property>();
    properties1.add(p1);
    properties1.add(p2);

    myCustomTree.put("depth1", properties1);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for interesting, but what you have described is just a structure for the data. What I am asking for is how to put such data into some kind of TreeTable like this: http://keeskuip.home.xs4all.nl/jmeld/images/ScreenShotFolderDiff.png , but in this image there are only check boxes in a column and I need to put there different controls for different rows. In my question the property | checkbox is not that I have "checkbox" string in there but a pure check box control.

Comment: then add another variable in the class to store the controlValue along with controlType for each Property.. Ok let me edit the above code.

Comment: I actually cannot understand the answer, you mean that I can use the myCustomTree as an argument to some JTreeTable or what?

Comment: I know nothing about JTree.**. But I know that if we need to store something to use it, then we can parse the contents and create a datastructure like the above or something. We can do if property.equals(""checkbox){ create a checkbox...}